# Why is numpy/pandas returning only the first character when I use .astype(str)

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to use the .astype() function to convert from an int32 to string. I first noticed this when trying to use the conversion on a pandas series, but when I tested with numpy I saw the same behavior, so I'm assuming that numpy is the underlying cause.

```
In [0]: import numpy as np
In [1]: test = np.array([1, 22, 333, 4444])
In [2]: test.astype(str)
Out [2]: array(['1', '2', '3'],
              dtype='|S1')
```

Why is it defaulting to S1 and not S4, as I would expect in order to capture the full length? It seems simple, but maybe there's something I'm missing? When I explicitly specify S3 (or greater) it works fine:

```
In [3]: test.astype('S10')
Out [3]: array(['1', '22', '333', '4444'],
              dtype='|S10')
```

Based on the examples I've seen online, it doesn't seem like I should have to specify this way. I've got numpy 1.6.1 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll also reach another snag with `numpy` when you hit 65 characters, but pandas works around this because each `str` object is stored as an opaque pointer to a Python object, not a `numpy.string_` type.

```
In [18]: from pandas.util.testing import rands

In [19]: s = Series([rands(120) for _ in range(10)])

In [20]: s
Out[20]:
0    LdeUwCKNFi4SWWfnAsKK3VIdDegy35lokoOr5DfCePoGn2...
1    xXmofyBFUfCiApbqNEDtJs6JhU0QAhIG8sQRCKkKMdTZuZ...
2    t3XcQFDQhg8BxAc9vFeo5Ky6beMxp9IGj54u3OzELR8lRf...
3    tWufKLo4OiW8lMpB8NiHzy0REAnAtAmLrDJyLzi1GBSRwS...
4    bysGao2rhiqxfmv54eDT6qcshlk0E7srrRLnuBDRRu7oVg...
5    AYIZFysXR9vispYQEfwqaZ20YYvR52pPkBtd2acOapK3Mv...
6    eLAwKopRuynrY75dn7vEfUnqhoSDLh5mGSBclFDaItwyxJ...
7    oj8ilX2EvhegAI4FvZQxJU0hTDR04aLySNdCXPmqOLa6CF...
8    5mEX5o23PMg5yWEE6bofk5tqzPCFNNCIn1v3ynYxicVXa8...
9    c2fS5Z1w7IxKq72x5KM8WhNChfrEJoFavdD1DQUJn4NCNP...
dtype: object

In [21]: s.astype(str).map(len)
Out[21]:
0    120
1    120
2    120
3    120
4    120
5    120
6    120
7    120
8    120
9    120
dtype: int64

In [22]: map(len, s.values.astype(str))
Out[22]: [64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64]
```

To be fair to `numpy`, this was fixed in pull request [#3270](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/3270) and is fixed in numpy 1.8.

**EDIT:** to address the initial issue (which was converting an `int` array to a `str` array), since you've tagged this as `pandas` you can do

```
In [4]: s = Series([1, 22, 333, 4444])

In [5]: s
Out[5]:
0       1
1      22
2     333
3    4444
dtype: int64

In [6]: s.astype(str)
Out[6]:
0       1
1      22
2     333
3    4444
dtype: object
```

This will work in older-than-1.7 `numpy`, but you'll have to upgrade to a later version of `pandas`, one at or after [`f0c1bd`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/commit/f0c1bd2994d08501ca5c4717d2f0754f70762528). Alternatively you can do

```
In [3]: s = Series([1, 22, 333, 4444])

In [4]: s.map(str)
Out[4]:
0       1
1      22
2     333
3    4444
dtype: object
```

which should work on any `pandas` version that has the `map` method on `Series` objects and any numpy version that is supported by `pandas`.

Comment: `>>> np.array(['a'*500])
array([ 'aaa..*snip*..aaa'],
      dtype='|S500')` Seems to work fine, can you elaborate?

Comment: You're not calling `astype`. The bug occurs with calls to `astype`, not when you construct the array explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

In 1.7.1 it works correctly. It was probably a bug.

```
In [11]: test = np.array([1, 22, 333, 4444])
In [12]: test.astype(str)
Out[12]: array(['1', '22', '333', '4444'], dtype='|S24')
In [13]: np.version.version
Out[13]: '1.7.1'
```

Comment: Yeah, worked fine when I upgraded. I just assumed it was me, though, since I almost never encounter bugs in core numpy functions!